# Equivalence of differentiability on regular surface

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

i need to prove that the two following definitions of differentiability on regular surfaces are equivalent:

Let $S$ be a regular surface. A function $f: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$ is differentiable if:

**i)** for any local chart of $S$ like $X: U \rightarrow S$ we have $f \circ X : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$ differentiable.

**or**

**ii)** for every point $p$ in $S$ there exists a local chart $X_p : U_p \rightarrow S$ around $p$ such that $f \circ X_p: U_p \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$ is differentiable.

Clearly **i** implies **ii** but i'm not seeing how **ii** implies **i**. Can anyone help me?

Thx!

Comment: Any chart is a local chart. $U_p$ is just notation for an open set $U$ that happens to contain the point $p$.

Comment: How does this help? I don't get it. Thanks!

Comment: Checking differentiability is a pointwise/local condition. Given any $U$, write it as a union of $U_p$'s.

Comment: can u write it more precisely? I didn't get your point. I understand i can get $U$ as a union of $U_p$'s, but i do not understand how this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The key point is the compatibility requirement for two overlapping charts in $S$. Suppose $X\colon U\to S$ is a chart and $p\in X(U)$. Then there is, by assumption, a chart $X_p\colon U_p\to S$ with $p\in X_p(U_p)$. By definition of a surface,
$$X_p^{-1}\circ X\big|_{X^{-1}(X_p(U_p)\cap X(U))}\colon X^{-1}(X_p(U_p)\cap X(U))\to X_p^{-1}(X_p(U_p)\cap X(U))$$
is a differentiable map from an open subset of $\Bbb R^2$ to another. But then $f\circ X = \big(f\circ X_p\big)\circ \big(X_p^{-1}\circ X)$ is the composition of differentiable functions on a neighborhood of $X^{-1}(p)$ and is differentiable.